# How to get View-goto-percent defined at startup

Tags: emacs, emacs23

If I startup emacs with `emacs -q`, then emacs does not know about the command `M-x View-goto-percent`, (which allows one to hop around large files by percent value).

However, if I type `C-h a percent` (search apropos "percent"), it finds the `View-goto-percent` command and I can then use it thereafter.

Why is this happening, and what should I put in `.emacs` so that `M-x View-goto-percent` is available at startup?

My emacs version (`M-x version`) is:

```
GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.6) of 2012-09-21 on roseapple, modified by Debian
```

Comment: With `emacs -q` `.emacs` won't be loaded, so I fail to see the point of your question.  Generally, update to a recent Emacs release first.

Comment: The `emacs -q` is here to make the problem easily reproducible. I'm not using `-q` in real life :).

Comment: Well, just `require` the file containing `View-goto-percent` (most likely `view.el`, hence `(require 'view)`).  Or add an autoload `(autoload 'View-goto-percent "view")'.

Comment: Thanks, @lunaryorn. Would you like to post it as a solution?

Comment: I added a corresponding answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `require` the library containing `View-goto-percent`:

```
(require 'view)
```

Alternatively, create an autoload for this function to load it automatically on its first use:

```
(autoload 'View-goto-percent "view")
```

Answer (score 3):

View-goto-percent is of the minor-mode view, so you shoud enable the function with view-mode-enter